# a turborepo pipeline task that depends on a root package.json task that does not execute in each package

Tags: turborepo

I have a root package.json task that does not execute in every package that calls `yarn tsc`.

Currently, I have it as a `prebuild` script in the root package.json:

```json
"prebuild": "yarn tsc",
```

Is there anyway to specify this as a `dependsOn` element of `build` in the `turborepo.json`?

If I add `tsc` like below then it will get executed in the each package which is not what I want.

```json
"pipeline": {
  "tsc": {
    "dependsOn": ["generate"],
    "outputs": ["dist-types/**"]
  },
  "build": {
    "dependsOn": ["tsc", "^build"],
    "outputs": ["dist/**"]
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `//#` prefix to specify a root tasks

```
"pipeline": {
  "//#tsc": {
    "dependsOn": ["generate"],
    "outputs": ["dist-types/**"]
  },
  "build": {
    "dependsOn": ["//#tsc", "^build"],
    "outputs": ["dist/**"]
  }
```

https://turbo.build/repo/docs/core-concepts/monorepos/running-tasks#running-tasks-from-the-root

Answer (score -1):

Based on [the documentation](https://turborepo.org/docs/getting-started#create-a-pipeline), your individual projects within the mono-repo need to implement a corresponding script (e.g. if you have `tsc` as a pipeline in `turbo.json`, you will need a `tsc` script in your `package.json` in your individual projects). Any project without a script matching the pipeline name will gracefully be skipped when the pipeline is run.

In your case, you would move your `tsc` script from the root level `package.json` into each project in which you want the pipeline to run against.

Comment: No, it is possible to run root level tasks after this landed https://github.com/vercel/turborepo/pull/1040#pullrequestreview-939899052